# Can you identify this Jaguar rear end?

Tags: suspension, part-identification, parts, jaguar, rear-end

Can you identify what type of Jaguar rear end this is and the model year?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture of the back side of the differential (rear cover) would help here tremendously.

Comment: Also, a pic of the outside hub area (where the wheel attaches).

Comment: Any serial numbers that are legible?

Comment: I will get additional photos today.

Answer (score 1):

Jaguar XJ independent rear suspension - not sure exactly what year though...

Comment: are you sure it's from an XJ? The XJS and E-type rear ends look similar.

Comment: The only way would be to have all the numbers possible and track the production dates to be sure - if that is possible...